# Skipping Certain Numbers Within For Loop

Tags: javascript, html

I was just coding a page to view every ASCII entry by entity number and I was wondering if perhaps there's a easier/cleaner method of skipping unwanted numbers.

```
<div id="ul-container">
    <ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var x = new Array();
            x[127] = 127;
            x[129] = 129;
            x[141] = 141;
            x[143] = 143;
            x[144] = 144;
            x[157] = 157;
            x[160] = 160;
            x[173] = 173;
            for (i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
                if (i >= 1 && i <= 32) {}
                else if (i == x[i]) {}
                else {
                    document.write("<li>&#" + i + "<br /><span>&amp;#" + i + "</span></li>");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/absolutebob/af9xpm5k/

Comment: I would use the `continue`.

Comment: If you mean how to make the code cleaner, you can define an array of unwanted numbers, and use indexOf() or jQuery $.inArray() to detect the invalid numbers.

Comment: Do **not** skip *bad* numbers, apply your logic only to *good* numbers instead.

Comment: HTML numeric character references use Unicode. (ASCII has only 128 characters numbered 0 to 127.) For characters U+0000 to U+001F, you could substitute the [Control Picture](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf) characters U+2400 to U+241F. For example: **␀** `&#x2400;`

Comment: Thanks for all your input guys. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think use this to skip by checking if `i` is in `x` and using the `continue` keyword:

```
if ((i >= 1 && i <= 32) || x.indexOf(i) > -1) continue;
```

and put values in the `x` array normally:

```
var x = [127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157, 160, 173];
```

```html
<div id="ul-container">
<ul>
    <script>
        var x = [127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157, 160, 173];
        for (i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
        if ((i >= 1 && i <= 32) || x.indexOf(i) > -1) continue;
            document.write("<li>&#" + i + "<br /><span>&amp;#" + i + "</span></li>");
        }
    </script>
</ul>
</div>

<style>
#ul-container {
border-style: none solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #000000;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 400px;
}
#ul-container li {
background-color: #f3f3f3;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 36px;
margin: 12px;
text-align: center;
}
#ul-container li span {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
```